# Using @Override annotation when child class method signature is changed

Tags: java, annotations, overriding

So, I am trying to better understand how Java override works.

I have created this basic code:

```
     public class A { 
    
       public void foo(String s) {
           System.out.println("inside A");
            }
      }
      public class B extends A{ 
    
       public void foo(String s, String g) {
           super.foo(s);
           System.out.println("inside B");
            }
      }
```

This code compiles fine, and though the signature is different on the child method (2 arguments instead of one), the usage `super` does not cause any errors. That, in my eyes means that the compiler understands this as overriding a method.

Yet when I add the `@Override` annotation on the `foo` method in `class B`, then I get a compile error saying:

```
java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

as if my override attempt is no longer correct.

So I am a bit confused as to why this is happening, and what changes when I add the annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"the compiler understands this as overriding a method"* - Incorrect, it is NOT an overriding method if the signature is different.  The use of `super` here is redundant, it would work just fine without `super`.

Comment: So practically, when the signature is changed, there is no longer an overriding of the parent class. Furthermore, the use of 'super' in this type of case is considered pleonastic, though it does not cause any compile errors. Your answer is very straightforward and clear, but the false-positive compilation of 'super' is what confused me.